# NodeJS Script - Can't connect to Websocket

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache, http, port

I am attempting to create a websocket on my webserver. I would like to connect to the websocket from my client to update information on the website.. However, when I try connecting, I get the following error in Postman:

> Error: Unexpected server response: 101
> Handshake Details
> Request URL: https://example.com:8443/radar
> Request Method: GET
> Status Code: 101 Switching Protocols
> Request Headers
> Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
> Connection: Upgrade
> Upgrade: websocket
> Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
> Host: example.com:8443
> Response Headers
> Date: Sat, 11 Mar 2023 02:20:55 GMT
> Server: Apache/2
> Upgrade: websocket
> X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger 5.3.7
> Status: 101 Switching Protocols
> Vary: User-Agent
> Content-Length: 2

To listen on port 8443, I have the following in my VirtualHosts (httpd.conf):

```
Listen 8443
<VirtualHost 123.123.123.123:8443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/admin/domains/example.com.cert.combined
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/admin/domains/example.com.key
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/admin/domains/example.com/private_html
    UseCanonicalName OFF
    <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
        SuexecUserGroup admin admin
    </IfModule>
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domains/example.com.bytes bytes
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domains/example.com.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/domains/example.com.error.log

    # Allow WebSocket connections
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/radar [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} upgrade [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/radar/(.*)$ wss://localhost:8443/radar/$1 [P,L]

    <Directory /home/admin/domains/example.com/private_html>
        AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo Indexes Limit Options=Indexes,IncludesNOEXEC,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch,FollowSymLinks,None
        Options -ExecCGI -Includes +IncludesNOEXEC
        php_admin_flag engine ON
        php_admin_value sendmail_path '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f admin@example.com'
        php_admin_value mail.log /home/admin/.php/php-mail.log
        php_admin_value open_basedir /home/admin/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/opt/alt/php74/usr/share/pear/:/dev/urandom:/usr/local/lib/php/:/usr/local/php74/lib/php/
    </Directory>

    # Mail auto configuration (Thunderbird, MS Outlook)
    ProxyPassMatch "^/\.well-known/autoconfig/mail/config-v1\.1\.xml$|^/([Aa]utodiscover)/\1\.xml$" "unix:/usr/local/directadmin/shared/internal.sock|http://localhost"
</VirtualHost>
```

The code for the NodeJS script is as follows:

radar.js:

```
const http = require('http');
const WebSocketServer = require('websocket').server;
const fs = require('fs')

function writeHtml(outputStream) {
    const inputStream = fs.createReadStream('index.html')

    inputStream.pipe(outputStream)

    outputStream.on('finish', () => {
        console.log('served')
        outputStream.end();
    })
    outputStream.on('error', (e) => {
        console.error('errors', e)
        outputStream.end();
    })
}

const server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  writeHtml(res)
})

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 8443);
const wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
    httpServer: server
});

wsServer.on('request', function(request) {
    console.log("ws received")
    const connection = request.accept(null, request.origin);
    connection.on('message', function(message) {
      console.log('Received Message:', message.utf8Data);
      connection.sendUTF('Hi this is WebSocket server!');
    });
    connection.on('close', function(reasonCode, description) {
        console.log('Client has disconnected.');
    });
});
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>WebSocket Playground</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<script>
  
const ws = new WebSocket('wss://' + location.host);
ws.onopen = function() {
    console.log('WebSocket Client Connected');
    ws.send('Hi this is web client.');
};
ws.onmessage = function(e) {
  console.log("Received: '" + e.data + "'");
};
</script>
</html>
```

I have tried modifying the VirtualHosts too, but that didn't achieve anything.

I would appreciate any help I can get, I am also not using a proxy (like Cloudflare, etc). Thank you.

Edit: Tried using ws instead, over port 8880 on a non-ssl connection with the virtual host configurations. Still the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

you added an extra 's' in connection string in client

```js
const ws = new WebSocket('wss://' + location.host);
```

replace with:

```js
const ws = new WebSocket('ws://' + location.host);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am wanting to connect over port 8443, which has SSL enabled, and therefore I would like to use wss. However, even if I manually connect with wss://example.com:8443/radar, it doesn't connect (error shown in post). So, it won't be an issue with the HTML.